# no css effect when printing!

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, printing

I made a page contains specific control, and i used CSS and it works okay and applied on the page, but when i print the control which contains my data , no effect to the CSS on the paper . what is the problem ?
the control exists in div.

Comment: What kind of effect is it and what code are you using for it?

Comment: What happens if you put all your CSS rules inside an "@media all { }" block? (Should make no difference, but if it were me I'd try it.)

Comment: If you mean no background images are printed it's the default browser behavior and there's nothing you can do. Otherwise please give more details.

Comment: sorry meant background in general, images *and* colors. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326 see my answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background colors and images won't be printed by default by most browsers.

IE reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326

Firefox reference: [How do I Make Firefox Print a Background-Color Style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764520/how-do-i-make-firefox-print-a-background-color-style)

Easy enough to find for any other browser if you want.

Answer (score 2):

have you used `@media` inside the css source or the media-attribute eg `media="screen"`inside the html source code? that might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check this interesting read at A List Apart: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

It is a comprehensive guide at using print style sheets.