# CSS How to print a table with background color (without Print settings changes)

Tags: css, html-table

The aim is to print table with colored td-s.
I need a way correct for all types of browsers.

Is there any way?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that most browsers default to NOT printing backgrounds. There's nothing you can do to change that when you're just printing from HTML. You could convert it to PDF, but I don't know if that would be feasible for you.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764520/how-do-i-make-firefox-print-a-background-color-style/34379688#34379688

Comment: This should not be a problem any longer. I came to this issue because I had a bootstrap page and bootstrap has an `@media print` query which removes background colors from tables (e.g. stripes).

Comment: @maria both Firefox and Chrome give the option now (i.e. in 2018) `Print Background Color` and `Background graphics` respectively to get the job simply done now. When these option are disabled then all CSS options become useless.

Answer (score 78):

For Chrome, Safari and Firefox:

```
body{
  -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact !important;
  print-color-adjust:exact !important;
}
```

Comment: Above worked in chrome browser.I selected the print background images and color check box in firefox and checked it,it is not printing the background image.Is it possible to set css like above for firefox for printing background image.

Comment: It is not possible in non-webkit browsers such as Firefox.

Comment: It is now, with `color-adjust:exact`. In FF anyway.

Comment: I have used these above code. I am facing problem in invoice. I have made dynamic bill for client that contains table tds and trs with decent bg color but when we do print then the bg color of trs is white. So to out come these problem I used these command

Comment: CSS rule is now `print-color-adjust: exact;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/print-color-adjust

Comment: @Carl Thanks. I added it to my answer for Firefox support. Chrome and Safari still need the -webkit prefix.

Answer (score 34):

Quote from here: [CSS @media print issues with background-color;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color)

> IF a user has "Print Background
>   colours and images" turned off in
>   their print settings, no CSS will
>   override that, so always account for
>   that. This is a default setting.
>
> Once that is set so it will print
>   background colours and images, what
>   you have there will work.
>
> It is found in different spots. In
>   IE9beta it's found in Print->Page
>   Options under Paper options
>
> In FireFox it's in Page Setup ->
>   [Format & Options] Tab under Options.

Answer (score 5):

For chrome you can use this:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
```

Or in print preview, set the checkbox *'More settings->Background Graphics'*

[image]

For Firefox, I couldn't find anything to enable it using CSS. However, you can enable it as follow (If you don't see the File, press Alt key once).
*'File->Page setup'* and set the checkbox *'Print Background(color & images)'*

[image]

Comment: As noted in a comment by @voidstate, in Firefox it is possible by using "color-adjust:exact" .

Answer (score 4):

a particularly ugly solution is to place position a .gif (or any form of vector graphic so the size can be changed) image  in the table cell with height and width 100% then a negative z-index property.

Answer (score 4):

I found [@willert's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9300996/835945) a bit consistent and easy. I have developed it further, hope it helps you guys...

```
table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    font:13px/1.5 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
}

table td,
table th {
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 12px;
}

table th:before,
table td:before {
    content: "";
    padding: 0;
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: 10px -994px -996px -2px;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
    top: -6px;
}

table th:before {
    border-top: 999px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-left: 999px solid #D6D6D6;
}

table td:before {
    border-top: 999px solid #F9F9F9;
    border-left: 999px solid #F9F9F9;
}
td div.grid_3{
    overflow: hidden;
}
table .row td{
    border-bottom: #d6d6d6 1px solid;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution that isn't horribly ugly, like positioning image or ridiculously large border underneath the table.

It depends what you need those backgrounds for. If it's decorative, then it may be better not to force it.

If it's to highlight some table cells, you can use color `border` in addition to the background. Borders are printed.

If it's very important that backgrounds are printed, then you may give users a PDF to print.

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing around to solve this problem, and CSS content generation and modern browsers seem to provide a nice solution to this problem. NOT WIDELY TESTED, FEEDBACK WELCOME!

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table td,
table th {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

table th:before,
table td:before {
    content: "";
    padding: 0;
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -4px -994px -996px -6px;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
    top: -500px;
}

table th:before {
    border-top: 999px solid #c9c9c9;
    border-left: 999px solid #c9c9c9;
}

table td:before {
    border-top: 999px solid #eeeeee;
    border-left: 999px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

You will need to handcraft the details to fit your needs.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Judging from my research on this, you're not likely to find a CSS solution that covers everything.  You might be able to apply a jQuery solution to this.

```
<style>
.cell_pos {
    position: relative;
}
.cell_cont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.img_color {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
}
</style
<table>
    <tr class="row1">
        <td class="selected">
            <div class="cell_pos">
                <div id="cell_cont">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#row1 .selected).append('<img class="img_color" src="path/to/img.jpg/>');
    )};
</script>
```

The question was a little vague so you would probably need some work around with the css with `overflow`  and setting cell/column widths.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me and wont affect your other CSS code:

```
@media print {
    div {
       background: #333333 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Use `!important` in your CSS and it will print, in Chrome.

Comment: I tested this on chrome. The Row has a background-color inline style set to silver. I added the !important; command at the end. No effect on Chrome printing.

Comment: IF a user has "Print Background colours and images" turned off in their print settings, no CSS will override that, so always account for that. This is a default setting.

Comment: @BjörnC. Thanks dude you saved my tons of hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little coloring the background by putting the contents in as an input-tag  of type submit and set value to John Doe. then use class or style to manipulate the coloring. Never the less the browser will change the forecoler to black so only use light backgrounds but it works (a little).

Answer (score 1):

I tried all suggested solutions here (and in many other questions), such as applied `background-color: #000 !important;` both in stylesheet and inline, or set

```
@media print {
  * {
    color-adjust: exact !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  }
}
```

, even combined them together, but nothing worked.

After hours of researching without any results, I recognized that the "*bug*" lost background-color only appears on table (th, td), but other HTML elements (div,...) or other CSS attributes (border-color,...) still work.

Therefore, I came up with a "*hack*" to wrap-up anything inside `<th>` or `<td>` with a `<div>` (you can adjust padding to make it display same as prior).

Here I used React and `makeStyles` of `@material-ui/core`.

JSX:

```
<Table bordered>
  <thead className={classes.thead}>
    <tr>
      <th><div>Col 1</div></th>
      <th><div>Col 2</div></th>
      <th><div>Col 3</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td className={classes.tdGreen}><div>Row 1 - Col 1</div></td>
      <td><div>Row 1 - Col 2</div></td>
      <td><div>Row 1 - Col 3</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Row 2 - Col 1</div></td>
      <td className={classes.tdBlue}><div>Row 2 - Col 2</div></td>
      <td><div>Row 2 - Col 3</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

Styles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  thead: {
    textAlign: 'center',

    '& th:not(:last-child)': {
      padding: '0',
      '& > div': {
        padding: '.75rem',
        backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8 !important',
      }
    }
  },
  tdGreen: {
    padding: '0 !important',
    '& > div': {
      padding: '.75rem',
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'green !important',
    }
  },
  tdBlue: {
    padding: '0 !important',
    '& > div': {
      padding: '.75rem',
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'blue !important',
    }
  }
}));
```

You can take the idea and convert it into pure HTML/CSS solutions.

Hope this can help anyone struggled with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
            <td><img src="your_image" /></td>
```

Comment: Why does this not work? Seems like the only working solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

This silly solution worked for me on Firefox and Chrome (Ubuntu).

**Firefox:** Open the print dialog box (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and goto `Options` tab,
and make sure that the option `Print Background Colors` is ticked.

[image: Firefox's Print Settings]

**Chrome:** Open the print dialog box (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and expand `More settings` and tick `Background graphics`.

[image: Chrome's Print Settings]

As far as I have tested, `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` doesn't work for Firefox and is honored in Chrome. But in both the browsers the final printing option overrides all that. **So you can completely do away without it.**

Try printing the following sample HTML page with and without the various settings described here and you will know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="border-width:1px;width:50%;">
    <tr style="background-color:#999999">
      <td>First Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#CCCCCC">
      <td>Second Row</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use this in the weasyprint library that generates pdf's from python. if all you want to do is print a pdf then use the @print property with !important

e.g

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @media print {
                .a {
                    background: orange !important;
                }
                .b {
                    background: blue !important;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="a">This cell has an orange background.</td>
                <td class="b">This cell has a green background.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

You will notice that if you open this in a web browser you wont see the colors, put if you print it as a pdf you will. because those styles are applied on printing

if you wanted to also view the colors in the browser you would add the same styles as normal outside of print

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
                .a {
                    background: orange;
                }
                .b {
                    background: blue;
                }

            @media print {
                .a {
                    background: orange !important;
                }
                .b {
                    background: blue !important;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="a">This cell has an orange background.</td>
                <td class="b">This cell has a green background.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

for printing PDF's you only need the @print property

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class to the  background with setting background image and !important. The method does not require setting background printing.

**HTML**

<td class="red"></td>

**CSS**

.red { background-image: url('images/bg-red.jpg') !important; }