# When I print my webpage I lose all the css colouring. Is there an option or script to print a webpage exactly how it looks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

My webpage has a table mainly. The tables columns have different background.

When I print I lose the background colours even though I am printing in colour.

The colours are not gray, they just don't come up

Comment: possible duplicate of [print css style not shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580324/print-css-style-not-shown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually specify that the background gets printed in your browser options, at least in Firefox you can anyway.

[image]

Comment: This works great on firefox. where do I find that option in IE6?

Comment: Oh, IE6... Hmm, I don't have that available I don't think. Let me see if it is on any of our servers...

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly a CSS issue.  Check your stylesheet MEDIA type http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html