# What do printers ignore?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

When printing an HTML document [the bgcolor of a table cell is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5110833/569976).

What else is ignored when one tries to print documents?

I'm trying to make a particular website look a certain way when printed out but am having some difficulty doing so not knowing what attributes printers use and which ones they ignore.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can always make explicit style rules by putting CSS inside a `@media print { ... }` block. Also it's not the *printer* that does the work here; it's what the browser sends to be printed that matters.

Answer (score 2):

The link you're referring to is about browser-specific print handling. Check out the each supported browser's printing properties for more info there.

Regularly, though, WYSIWYG when it comes to printing an HTML page.

You could specify a specific CSS file for printing by adding the following tag to your `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Where `print.css` is the path to your CSS file.

**Addition**:
Though you *can't* override the Browser-preferences, there's nothing you can do to print your BG in non-allowing browsers. Check the printing preferences for those options.
My best idea is to export your web-page to PDF and print that. See [web2pdfconvert](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/), for example of such a service. You could also install a plugin on your server side that does exactly the same thing, and the send it your HTML via AJAX.

**Another Addition:** Take a look at [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf) which is completely client side and thus simpler. You can use it to convert the page to pdf and than print it as it is.

Comment: Setting media="print" still doesn't result in background's working: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6670151/569976

Comment: It shouldn't. I explained above.

Answer (score 1):

Things that may be ignored are completely dependent upon the browser in question and the print settings for that browser.

For example, in Chrome you can turn off headers/footers and backgrounds.  In Firefox you have control over backgrounds.  In IE you have some refined control over frames, linked documents and optionally printing a table of links.

Your best bet is to simply provide a style sheet for `media="print"` and define how you want the page to look.

Comment: Things also depend on the physical printer. You can’t make a black and white printer produce colors. Moreover, handling of units tends to vary; `10pt` on screen may differ from `10pt` in print.