# turn on printing background colors and images with css? (renamed from css print pseudo element and element background print)

Tags: html, css, printing, css-animations, pseudo-element

I need to make a css animation with element and its pseudo :before 
CSS and at the same time keep the ablility to print the last state:

```
.pump:before {
        content:"";
        width:100px;
        border: 1px solid #0ca3da;
        top:-4px;
        left:-1px;
        height:100px;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
    }
    .pump {
        height:10px;
        width:50%;
        top:4px;
        background:#0ca3da;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        animation: pump 1s;

    } 
    @keyframes pump {0%   {width: 0px;}}
    @-webkit-keyframes pump {0%   {width: 0px;}}
    .wrap {
        display: inline-block;
        width : 95px;
    }

#pmp {width:34px;}
```

on the screen I need to animate it like here: http://jsfiddle.net/iskren/L3khm/6/
and on the print media I need to show last state of the move only

In Google Chrome I use ctrl+p and my Options for Printing "Background colors and images" was turned off. So question now is there any way to set this option to on when chosen to print

Comment: Are you talking about printing a physical copy of the page from a printer?

Comment: What do you mean by print?

Comment: in Chrome I send ctrl+p command and on the screen there the background of the element with "pump" class is not visible

Comment: @GhostGambler i have not tried to use javascript and two div tags.
I also try using `display:inline-bolck !important;` in here http://jsfiddle.net/iskren/L3khm/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be in this thread for webkit user:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14784681/3345926

using:

```
body{
  -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
}
```