# Does WebBrowser Control remove color formatting when printing html string?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, printing

I am trying to print content of WebBrowser Control. When I save the content as .xps file , I see no color in the table when I right click the webbrowser control and click print. Does webbrowser control remove color formatting when printing? There has to be some explanation.

```
 WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<table border='1' > <tr><td bgcolor='blue'>No Color</td></tr> </table>"
```

I am able to see color in the webbrowser control but it removes color when saving it as xps?

Comment: `WebBrowser` control uses the Internet Explorer version currently installed on the computer.

Comment: I have IE8 and BrowserCotnrol renders html just fine. It is only when I print this BrowserControl that it loses its color formatting.

Answer (score 2):

It's a browser setting.

Your browser (Internet Explorer) is not set up to print background colors and images. I don't think you can easily change that programmaticaly but it might be possible.
See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110833/css-how-to-print-a-table-with-background-color-without-print-settings-changes) for better explanation of the issue and possible solutions.

I ran in to the same issue some time ago, where the printed page just had to look excactly like the webpage, and ended up spending a lot of time creating a PDF file to send the user instead.

I think it might be possible to find a registry key to set for Internet Explorer so the setting is automaticly set.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main The value
>   is "Print_Background"
>   [source](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/ie-background-printing-question-t730318.html)

Comment: Changing this key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup\Print_Background actually works well for me, you can save the current state with `string old_bg = key.GetValue("Print_Background").ToString();` and set the value to 'yes' before reseting original value