# Printing background-color in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, background-color

I am with some problems to print background-color in Firefox and IE. For Google Chrome I found the follow hack and it works well, but for Firefox and IE I can't find anything.

```
//Hack for Google Chrome
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
```

I am glad if someone can help me with this.

Comment: No one? Please, please help me sharing this post...

Comment: I added a hack here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764520/how-do-i-make-firefox-print-a-background-color-style/22632508#22632508

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS @media print issues with background-color;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color)

Answer (score 6):

```
* {
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
printer-colors: exact;
color-adjust: exact;}
```

**Browsers:** Chrome, Safari, FireFox

More: https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/print-backgrounds

Comment: IE - No. 
Edge (75+) - Yes

Answer (score 5):

For Firefox on the Print dialog there is an Advanced or Show Details button, if you click that , under Appearance there are two checkboxes.  One for Print Background Colors and Print Background Images.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I need something that not depends of the user, something in the application to print it automatically, like the hack to Google Chrome.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not possible without user interraction. html printing is really limited.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with having your element being a fixed height/width, you can set its size, put a 1px coloured image into it (of whatever colour you want the background to be) and make it fill the space. Then you can absolutely position your content on top.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <img src="/images/blue.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you could do the same thing with a border instead of an image:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 0; height: 0; border: 50px solid black;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

(Original idea from here: https://defuse.ca/force-print-background.htm)

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox

```
color-adjust:exact;
```

will work same as `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems impossible, as  Spark says, but you can sometime use wide borders as workaround (e.g. div with 0 height and 100px border).