# Force Background Color Printing on Firefox

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, firefox, printing

I'm using the [Barby](https://github.com/toretore/barby) ruby gem which adds a handy way to [render barcodes as HTML](https://github.com/toretore/barby/wiki/Outputters#html).

Barby renders a table with `td` backgrounds on or off based on the code passed to it. This works pretty well because I don't want to generate and store an image file for every record I need a barcode for.

The major browsers don't print background colors by default and I need the barcode to print without making the user change a print option on their local system.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this with Firefox. With webkit (Chrome and Safari), it's pretty easy:

```
td { 
  background: #000 !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Feverish Googling hasn't really gotten me anywhere: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947433/printing-background-color-in-firefox-and-ie) question is a few years old and I haven't found anything newer so I figure I'd pose the question again. [Fat borders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22632508/5455624) also won't really work because if the relationship between the bars change, it'll change the data contained in the code.

Comment: Surprisingly, it looks like some recent changes are making this work with the new color-adjust property. MDN doesn't even have documentation for it yet, so I think it might still be in development for now (September 2016)

Comment: Just to flag up that using `!important` does seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<strike>This is beginning to work in Firefox (at least version 48.0.2) with the "[color-adjust](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/#color-adjust)" property.</strike>

`color-adjust` was created for this, but is now deprecated and replaced with `print-color-adjust`: https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-color-adjust/#propdef-print-color-adjust
[image: Note in documentation showing color-adjust is deprecated in favor of the more specific print-color-adjust]

```
td { 
  background: #000 !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

The `forced-color-adjust` property is new in 2022 and starting to be adopted and may be useful in some situations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/forced-color-adjust

Comment: Good answer. Solved my problem.

Comment: Works great for bg colors. Is there any way for color property? Mine is nor printing the color if I set the color to white else it's working.

Comment: Still unofficial. Pretty good coverage though: https://caniuse.com/#search=color-adjust

Comment: @Frédéric it looks like they fixed it https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1436758 (I haven't tested it myself)

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
@media print {
    body {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; /*Chrome, Safari */
        color-adjust: exact; /*Firefox*/
    }
}
```