# Incorrect text colors when printing HTML page

Tags: css, printing

Why do browsers change the color of text when printing?

For example, create a blank HTML document containing:

```
<span style="color: #80b831">test</span>
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7z6c2/

The `span` has `color: #80b831` on the screen, but when printed (even just print preview in Chrome) the color is different (lime greenish).

[image: ScreenshotsfromPDFCreator]

If I tick Chrome's "Background colors and images" option in Print Preview, the correct color is then used.

What's happening here? How can I get the right color to appear by default? Is this something to do with "web-safe" colors?

Comment: it worked fine for me. Have you checked your ink cartridges?

Comment: The color is wrong even just in print preview

Comment: Please can you include enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself, not just in the fiddle.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764520/how-do-i-make-firefox-print-a-background-color-style/34379688#34379688

Answer (score 12):

Check this **[Fiddle](http://goo.gl/Befbwo)**

You have to use -webkit-print-color-adjust on the element which you are going to print

Also check here to know more about print color adjust https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust

Comment: That doesn't quite explain why the color is off if you don't use that option. It's not a background color.

Comment: The color change problem arises only when you try to print with chrome only.. without print color adjust try to print your page with firefox, then you can see its working..

Comment: That still doesn't explain why Chrome is doing it.

Comment: And yeah about the background color, as you can see when we check the option "Background color and images" in print preview its showing the right color.. so there must be something to do with background color only.

Comment: @Juhana: +1, while this can be used as a work-around for Chrome, it doesn't provide the reason (which was the original question).

Comment: +1 for Vikas. That Chrome's attribute is by default set to spare the printer toner. The allowed values are: `economy` vs `exact`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust

Answer (score 0):

A bit old topic but still this might have to do something with the web safe colors. Here is a [list](http://websafecolors.info/) of them, but haven't test it if there will be any difference due to the lack of printer.