# Puppeteer doesn't respect colors when exporting RMarkdown render to .pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, puppeteer

I am using `puppeteer` (headless Chrome) to render an .html generated by an RMarkdown script to .pdf. However, `puppeteer` doesn't seem to respect my `color` and `background-color` style settings. The problem doesn't exist when rendering pages off the web, suggesting it's the interaction between `puppeteer` and `RMarkdown`.

Consider the following `test.Rmd` script:

```
---
title: "Testing colors"
output: html_document
---

<style>
html {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

h4 {color: blue;}
</style>

#### Blue heading
<div style="color:red">This text is red</div>
<div style="background-color:red">This text has red background</div>
```

We can render it to `test.html` by calling `rmarkdown::render( "test.Rmd", output_file="test.html" )` in R. Note the `-webkit-print-color-adjust` setting; [it is often recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/764520/300187) as a solution to color-related problems, but I found that it has no effect in my case.

Following [puppeteer tutorials](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/get-started), I put together the following `render.js`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 400, height: 200});
    await page.goto('file:///home/sokolov/test/puppeteer/test.html');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'test.png'});
    await page.pdf({path: 'test.pdf', printBackground: true});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Running `node render.js` from the command line produces `test.png` and `test.pdf`. The former looks exactly how you would expect:

[image]

However, the `.pdf` loses all color specifications:

[image]

If I replace the url in my `render.js` with an external page (e.g., `https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp`), the page renders correctly in both `.png` and `.pdf` formats. Specifying `printBackground: true` was key to making it work for this external page, but it seems to have no effect of my local `test.html`.

Any thoughts on how to get the colors working?

**P.S.** To briefly address the question of why I'm not simply using `output: pdf_document` in my `.Rmd`, I wanted to note that the real RMarkdown document I'm working with uses `flexdashboard` layout, which [doesn't play nicely with knitr](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/52). Most of the tutorials I've read suggest using a headless browser to render the final `.html` to `.png`/`.pdf`. The solution is working well for me, except for the loss of color styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Simplest Solution

Why not just try removing all `!important` tags? We're targeting the css embedded by `rmarkdown:render`. Just run some search and replace code, and puppeteer will correctly colorize a pdf made from the test.html. Run this in a shell with vim installed:

`echo "%s/%21important// | w!" | vim -e test.html`

And that's it! Below I just document my first attempt to solve this problem, and I explain why it might not be the best solution. Someone else may find it useful.

## My first attempt

Run this in a shell with vim installed:

`echo "%s/%40media%20print%7B.\{-}%7D// | w!" | vim -e test.html`

The above command overwrites `test.html` with the `@media print{}` styles partially removed. Though the `@media print{}` styles are not fully or cleanly removed, the new `test.html` has the desired effect.

### Here is what I'm doing

We're working on url-encoded css, so `%s/%40media%20print%7B.\{-}%7D//` is needed when I really wish to write this:

`%s/@media print{.\{-}}//`

The goal is to delete statements like this: `@media print {a: ""}` entirely. I don't properly handle nested brackets, so this script only partially delete statements like this `@media print {.a{a: ""};b{}...}` leaving everything after the first closing bracket untouched. That is a bug. I'm removing too little due to  non-greedy matching with `.\{-}` instead of greedy matching with `.*`, which may remove too much.

### Here's what I'm removing

I've [URL decoded](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the actual css in `test.html` for readability. You can see that I've deleted non-matching braces. Likely, the offending css is not actually deleted, but removing these lines sufficiently breaks the css to disable the offending css whenever `@media print` is detected. Anyway, removing these 6 matches solves the problem.

```
@media print{*,:after,:before{color:#000!important;text- 
shadow:none!important;background:0 0!important;-webkit-box- 
shadow:none!important;box-shadow:none!important}
```

`@media print{.visible-print{display:block!important}`

`@media print{.visible-print-block{display:block!important}`

`@media print{.visible-print-inline{display:inline!important}`

`@media print{.visible-print-inline-block{display:inline-block!important}`

`@media print{.hidden-print{display:none!important}`